# VBA: Show Data in Cells Based on Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

i have hundreds of entries in excel that shows resource data. i wanted to create an excel sheet that has a button that when clicked it will show data of the selected resource.

here's a snippet of the excel sheet.

[resource data should show here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmcwI.jpg)

i tried the following code but cant figure out how to show it on the fields

```
Dim FindEID As String
Dim Rng As Range

FindEID = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D17").Value
If Trim(FindEID) <> "" Then
    With Sheets("Roster").Range("C:C")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindEID, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto Rng, True
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you specifying to look after the max number of cells?

Comment: Based on a criteria which is a user name. I want other details to show on thw fields

Comment: the `.Find` will return a range object that represents the first cell where the match is found. Do you always expect to only find at most 1 cell that matches the criteria in the `C` column?

Comment: Where is the rest of the data stored relative to the name?

Comment: @ArcherBird - might have jumbled my logic here. :) Fairly new in doing VB. I expect to fill around 5 or more cells when a match comes up based on the Column criteria.

Comment: @Brotato - dataset is stored in a second worsheet

Comment: @Shilos_Dad - forgive me, but I need a bit more clarification. Here is my understanding so far: You have a username on sheet 1, D17. You want to look for that username in the C column of Sheet "Roster". When you find that username in column C, do you then want to retrieve values from other columns in the same row? Do you want to print these to some other cell back on Sheet 1?

Comment: @ArcherBird - yes you got it right.

Comment: @Shilos_Dad What columns are the other values in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I would propose you do something like this. Rather than using the `.Find` method, you should loop through the `C` column and grab the data you need as you find it. Something like this:

```
Sub mySub()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim outputRowNum As Integer



    'This will speed things up a bit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    strSearch = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D17").Value 'grab our serach value (I assume its a string here)
    outputRowNum = 4 'first output row in Sheet1.D column is row 4

    'grab the last used row in the third column on Roster tab
    lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Roster").Cells(Worksheets("Roster").Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Roster").Range("C1:C" & lastRow)
        If cell.Value = strSearch Then
            'Here, we found a match, so grab all the data you need and print it
            'to the range you want...
            'There are many ways to do this, I just use the Offset method to move over to the next column

            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & outputRowNum).Value = cell.Offset(0, 0) 'Column C
            outputRowNum = outputRowNum + 1

            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & outputRowNum).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1) 'column D
            outputRowNum = outputRowNum + 1

            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & outputRowNum).Value = cell.Offset(0, 5) 'column H
            outputRowNum = outputRowNum + 1

            'Note that you run the risk of overwriting the criteria that started out in
            'cell Sheet1!D17 if there are more than 4 matches. The code will still work,
            'you'll just lose that original value in D17.

        End If
    Next cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

With more information about which cells you want to copy from or print to, I can update this to meet your needs.

Comment: based from match found  i want the values of columns C, D, H along the same row to show in Sheet1 D4, D5, D6

Comment: So you want the rows from C, D, H transposed into a single column starting at Sheet1.D4. If multiple rows matches are found, would the additional rows from C, D, H just continue down the sheet1.D column? (...D7,D8,D9...)?

Comment: exactly what im lookng for. :)

Comment: I see just one issue with this... if you get enough matches, you could end up writing over sheet1.D17 - which is your criteria cell. Would overwriting that cause a problem for you?

Comment: it will cause problems if i remove the filters and show inactive resources also. right now it only shows active ones so overwriting it is close to 0%